# Minecraft spigot plugin, multiple args to string

Tags: java, minecraft

I'm trying to make plugin where player can change sign with command `/signeditor2 edit <Line-number> <text that can have spaces>`
But I just can't figure out how to do it.
This is my code but when i use it it only type on the sign first word of the message.
How can I connect all args after the Line number to one string and then put the string to the sign?

```
public class SignEditor implements CommandExecutor {

    
    public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String label, String[] args) {
        int al = args.length;
        if (label.equalsIgnoreCase("SignEditor")) {
            if (args[0].equalsIgnoreCase("Edit")){
                // player
                Player player = (Player) sender;
                String Sarg1 = args[1];
                int arg1 = Integer.parseInt(Sarg1);
                Block b = player.getTargetBlock(null, 10);
                
                if (sender instanceof Player) {
                    if (player.hasPermission("dg.SignEditor.edit.use")) {
                        if (args.length > 0 ) {
                            if (b.getType().name().contains("SIGN")) {
                                if ((arg1 - 1) > 3 || (arg1 -1 < 0)) {
                                    player.sendMessage(ChatColor.translateAlternateColorCodes('&', "&7<&6SignEditor&7> " + Main.plugin.getConfig().getString("Edit.Failed.InvalidLine")));      
                                }
                                else {
                                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(args[2]);
                                    for (int i = 2; i < al; i++) {
                                        sb.append(' ').append(args[i]);
                                    }
                                    String sbs = sb.toString();
                                    Block bx = player.getTargetBlockExact(10);
                                    Sign sign = (Sign) bx.getState();
                                    sign.setLine(arg1 - 1, sbs);
                                    sign.update();
                                    player.sendMessage(ChatColor.translateAlternateColorCodes('&', "&7<&6SignEditor&7> " + Main.plugin.getConfig().getString("Edit.Succsessfull")));
                                }
                            }
                            else player.sendMessage(ChatColor.translateAlternateColorCodes('&', "&7<&6SignEditor&7> " + Main.plugin.getConfig().getString("Edit.Failed.NoSign")));
                                return false;
                            }
                                
                        if (args.length <= 0) {
                            player.sendMessage(ChatColor.translateAlternateColorCodes('&', "&7<&6SignEditor&7> " + Main.plugin.getConfig().getString("Edit.Failed.NoArguments")));
                            return false;
                        }

                    }
                    player.sendMessage(ChatColor.translateAlternateColorCodes('&', "&7<&6SignEditor&7> " + Main.plugin.getConfig().getString("Edit.Failed.MissingPermissions")));
                    return true;
                }
                else
                    sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.translateAlternateColorCodes('&', "&7<&6SignEditor&7> " + Main.plugin.getConfig().getString("Edit.Failed.OnlyPlayers")));
                    
                
                return false;
            }
            if (args[0].equalsIgnoreCase("reload")) {
                Main.plugin.reloadConfig();
                Player player = (Player) sender;
                player.sendMessage(ChatColor.translateAlternateColorCodes('&', "&7<&6SignEditor&7> " + Main.plugin.getConfig().getString("reload.message")));
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
    public boolean isNum(String num) {
        try {
            Integer.parseInt(num);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: When you use your debugger, what does it say `args` and `sbs` are?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming we have a String array called args with the values `{"edit", "2", "first", "second", "first"}`, which would be existing if you type the command `/signeditor2 edit 2 first second first` we can apply `String.join` method on a subarray of our array.

```java
String argsToOneString = String.join(" ", Arrays.asList(args).subList(2, 5).toArray(new String[]{}));
```

When we print `argsToOneString` we get `first second third`.

Hope i could help you,

Luca

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid using multiple arguments like that in commands due to the way that Minecraft will interpret commands and spaces.

You should ideally use an alternative method for this input such as opening a new sign GUI or by capturing a chat message - the spigot wiki has [this answer](https://www.spigotmc.org/threads/solved-open-sign-gui-get-input-from-player.380079/)

Good luck with the plugin

Answer (score -1):

It's not the correct way to do this.

I would either capture a message in chat/have only 1 argument for it and replace "_" with spaces.

"This_is_a_new_line" becomes: "This is a new line".